# Yet another conjecture about primes

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, experimental-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{N}(n)$ be the next prime greater than $n$. Conjecture:

> $\mathcal{N}(n!)-n!\:$ is either $1$ or a prime.

It holds for n=1 to 99 and the expression is 1 for 3,11,27,37,41,73,77 and primes for all other $n<100$.

I have no idea how to proceed, but will go on testing for $n>99$.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not true, but it's quite possible you'll run out of numbers for which this is reasonable to verify before you find a counterexample.

Comment: might be somehow related with Wilson's theorem? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Comment: Since $\mathcal N(n!)-n!$ is coprime to every number $\le n$, any counterexample would need to have $\mathcal N(n!)-n! > n^2$.  On the other hand, the typical size of $\mathcal N(x)-x$ is $\log x/2$ by PNT.  Most of the time we should have $\mathcal N(n!)-n!$ about $n \log n$ in size, and Cramér's conjecture would limit this to $O(n^2 \log^2 n)$ in rare cases.  This is one reason why counterexamples are hard to find.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A002981 which extends your list.

Comment: The same has apparently been verified for $n<2000$ when you take a prime preceding $n$: [A033933](https://oeis.org/A033933).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is similar to Fortune's conjecture, with factorials replacing primorials. The relevant sequence in the OEIS is [A033932](https://oeis.org/A033932) where you can find your question as a 2004 conjecture by Amarnath Murthy. I expect others have asked the same question earlier. You can see that the conjecture has been verified for the first 2000 terms.

Answer (score 4):

I kept in my favorites your question, and finally this week I have a computer! so I did also some tests. I think that the rule could be generalized to something like this (1):

> (1) $\mathcal{N}(E(n))-E(n)\ \in \{0,1,\Bbb P\}$.

Where $E(n)$ is an expression based on $n$, and as @Charles mentioned, the known ones are: [Fortunate numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number) (using primorials), and the $n!$ version by [Amarnath Murthy](https://oeis.org/A033932) that you also found by yourself.

I have been trying other expressions and the following ones seem to comply as well (maybe they are known, but I just did some trial-error). I tested both over the interval $[1,300]$ with Python:

$E_1(n)=2^n\cdot n!$

I wondered if it was possible to find an expression $E(n) \lt n!$, and the following one seems to work as well! (at least up to $n=300$).

$E_2(n)=\frac{n!}{2^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}}$

I found other expressions (*) $E(n) \lt E_2(n)$ that seem also to comply with the original rule, but I am still testing them. The topic is really amazing (and must confess I did not know anything about it before).

(*) I tried also for instance Catalan numbers, but they do not comply.

In my humble opinion, one interesting point about your research would be:

> Which one is the minimum expression $E_{min}(n)$?
>
> $E_{min}(n)\ /$
>
> $\ \mathcal{N}(E_{min}(n))-E_{min}(n) \in \{0,1,\Bbb P\} \land$
>
> $\not \exists\ E(n)\ ,\ E(n) \lt E_{min}(n) \land \ \mathcal{N}(E(n))-E(n) \in \{0,1,\Bbb P\}$

**UPDATE (2015/05/14)**:

The following expression seems to comply as well, tested as far as I could with Pytyon in the interval $n \in [1..700]$

> $E_3(n) = (\frac{n}{2})^{(n-1-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)}$
>
> Where $(x)^k = x*(x+1)*...*(x+k-1)$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

The origin of the expression was the product of the even numbers $e \in [p,2p-2]$, where $p$ is a prime. Such expression can be written as $2^{k_1}(\frac{p}{2})^{k_2}$. That expression failed the test for few $p$'s. For that reason I tested separately $2^{k_1}$ and $(\frac{p}{2})^{k_2}$.

While the $2^{k_1}$ side failed, the Pochhammer side complied with the rule for all the primes up to $n=700$. Then I applied that same calculation for not only primes but any odd number, and also worked in the interval. And finally applied the same for any even number. So finally the candidate expression that works in the whole interval $[1,700]$ is the Pochhammer side of the initial expression I tested.

It would be cool to be able to test in a bigger interval (I cannot test it due to my laptop) because $E(n) = (\frac{n}{2})^{(n-1-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)}$
is much smaller than $n!$ so the computational cost is smaller (anyway they are semi factorials, so it takes time)

What I was not able to find yet is a power-based only expression. All of them require factorials...

Comment: I sympathize with your generalization and have thought in similar direction myself. But instead of functions E I have examined sets of primes and their products and have made a program that lists all the values in the prime gap including this product and studying corresponding differences for all numbers in the gap. There is no obvious pattern but the product of "a lot of" primes always seems to give a difference that is a prime.

Comment: @Lehs that is cool, please may I ask you a sample of a set of primes and their products that you use to understand better? sounds interesting! About the pattern, it could be anything, based on modularity, or related with binomial coefficients for example... by the way, I have found another expression smaller than E2 above, now in review at OEIS, tested up to n=600, maybe tomorrow will be ready, I will put it over here.

Comment: @Lehs thanks for the link... May I ask you a little bit more? for instance I can see n=1425172824437700885 whose factors are 3 5 599 8069 19657565689 but what I do not understand yet is how you get the difference as 2 for it. How is that calculated, with the same expression as on this question? by the way, I saw you other question today (the one that had a counterexample). I am testing more expressions like that, if I find something interesting I will put it here as well.

Comment: $\mathcal N(1425172824437700885)=1425172824437700887$ so the difference is 2. There is something interesting about this, but I can't put the finger on it yet.

Comment: @Lehs understood, the same operation... I am testing today another version, so far up to n=500 (the factorials consume all the memory!) I hope to have some news tomorrow, it might help you.

Comment: @Lehs I have update the explanation with the smaller expression than $n!$ that I was able to find. At least it works for $[1,700]$. Sorry if the explanation is not very good, just let me know if you want to know more details. :)

Comment: It seems that the reason for "coincidences" of this type is well explained in answers to my two related questions about this. And also, it seems impossible to explore coincidences experimentally, since eventually expected counterexamples are out of reach. I guess I leave this Q for the moment.