# Prime conjecture containing primorial: the difference between the primorial $n\#$ and the smallest prime $p > n\# + 1$ is always a prime

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, primorial

Help me find the exact conjecture statement. What I roughly remember is that it stated that the difference between primorial $n\#$ (product of first $n$ primes) and "some" larger number than the primorial (the number being well defined in the statement) is always a prime.

I simply cannot recall or find the exact statement... Does anyone know?

**Edit:** Thanks iadvd for help, let me just exact statement i had in mind for clarity:

> **Fortune's Conjecture:** For any integer $n>0$, the difference between the primorial $\#n$ and the smallest prime $p > n\#+1$ is always a prime.

Comment: my pleasure! indeed it is a very interesting topic to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are defining the [Fortunate numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number). Just an excerpt from Wikipedia: a Fortunate number, named after Reo Fortune, for a given positive integer n is the smallest integer m > 1 such that $p_n\# + m$ is a prime number, where the primorial $p_n\#$ is the product of the first $n$ prime numbers.

There are a lot of variations of this conjecture. For instance you can find some other questions at MSE regarding the topic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271433/yet-another-conjecture-about-primes) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283244/conjecture-about-the-product-of-the-primitive-roots-modulo-a-prime-number-pro).

Comment: Oh yes that is exactly it, the Fortunate's conjecture, thanks!